# What is falsy here ? Why does it dedupe? and why does console.log() contain the answer when infront of the foreach?

Tags: javascript

Q1-Why does this message print with the object even though it is before the forEach?
Q2-Why does this dedupe the new object
Q3-What triggers the falsy here that allow the {} to be added?

```
var test = [{id:1,name:'s1'},{id:2,name:'s2'},{id:2,name:'s2'},{id:1,name:'s1'},{id:4,name:'s4'}];

    var test1 = {};
    //Q1
    console.log(test1);

    test.forEach(function(item){
     //Q2 and Q3
     var o = test1[item.name] = test1[item.name] || {};
     o.id = item.id;
    });

    <!--Output 
    {}
    ​
    s1: Object { id: 1 }
    ​
    s2: Object { id: 2 }
    ​
    s4: Object { id: 4 }
    ​
    __proto__: Object { … }
     --!>
```

Comment: the console "lies" ... in Chrome (I'm assuming you use Chrome, because it seems that is the goto for average joes), it tells you what's happening if you hover over the blue `i` in the console output

Comment: it dedupes the new object because that's what the code does

Comment: Interesting, I was using fire fox. I tried chrome and the blue i said it just evaluated now.

Comment: Firefox also implements semi-live console logging - when you expand an object on the console, it shows object values when you clicked to expand, not when the object was logged. Refer to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log#Parameters).

Comment: None of the big browsers guarantee that `console.log` is a fully synchronous path. The *initial call* is handled synchronously, but actual logging may not be. So: if you need a true log, copy the thing you're logging a the time you're logging it. Slice() your arrays, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify()) object primitives, .copy() your classes etc.

Answer (score 2):

The console is tricky.  It does NOT lie, it just stores a reference to that object.  It's not "taking a picture" of the object as it is when you log it, it's actually reflecting the object itself.  If you were to update it on click, it would update that reference in the console, too.  If you alert it, you would get [object Object] instead of the text.  You can use `console.log(JSON.stringify(test1))` to print the contents as they were at the moment the object was read in the code.

As for deduping, it's pretty straight-forward, but a bit of a logic puzzle.  During one iteration, for example, it will see `test1['s1']` and assign it to 's1'.  The next time it runs across another s1, it's actually referencing the same property as before, `test1['s1']` and reassigning it to 's1' again.

I'll come back to take a closer look at question 3, but it's a good idea to ask one clear question at a time here on StackOverflow. ;)

--

Edit: Well, I'm not exactly sure about how you're getting those values in your log to be honest, because I'm not getting the same results even though I'm running the same script.  Check my code on [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rKZeWw) to see my script working as expected!

Comment: Hi, I was testing it in JsFiddle. Maybe that was adding to what was going on.

Answer (score 1):

Q1.  As discussed in comments, major browsers now log an inspectable tree of an object, not the conversion of the object to a string using its `toString` method. The tree is based on a reference to the object and may show property values current when expanding the tree rather than when the object was logged.

Q2. The `forEach` loop sets properties of `test1` using `item.name` values for items in the `test` array. If `name` values are repeated in `test` entries, only the one property name is updated in `test1`. Hence the de-duplication - an object can't store separate properties of the same name.

Q3. Initialisation of a `test1` property to an empty object only occurs the first time a property is created in `test1` for a property name held in `item.name`.  Subsequently, if the same value of `item.name` is encountered again, it retrieves the pre-existing property from `test1` because

```
test1[item.name] || {};
```

now evaluates to the existing `test1` object property. (If the left-hand operand of an `||` operator is non falsey, it returns the left-hand operator value as the result of the operation.)

That perhaps leaves the `o` variable - it is a copy of the reference to an object stored in `test1`. Updating its `id` property updates the same object as held in `test1`. If `test` had multiple entries of the same name but different `id` values, the `test1` property for the name would hold the `id` of the last duplicate entry in `test`.

Comment: Thank you , for the walk though and helping get my mind around that !